# Scroll to element on page using the elements id, Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

My question is simple, but I am struggling to find the answer. I am using meteor to create a website. With my meteor I am using iron router to navigate my pages AKA the templates. My head tag always stays the same. I only change the body by changing the template that is contained within the body using iron router. I have a page containing anchor tags with ids, **I want the page to automatically scroll to a certain anchor on my web page when my template changes due to the user navigating to that page**. Unfortunately I can only supply code snippets, because I am doing the webpage for a company and do not want to leak information. I think the code snippets will be sufficient.

I have tried the iron router onAfterRun:

```
Router.map(function(){
this.route("cpdEvents", {
    path: "cpd.html#events",
    onAfterRun: function() {
        e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("a[name=events]").offset().top
            }, 600);
    }
    });
});
```

And I have tried the template rendered function of meteor:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.cpd.rendered = function (){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("a[name=events]").offset().top
    }, 600);
}
}
```

Examples of the structure of my website, obvious not everything. Just the index html and the cpd.html where the user navigates to. The JavaScript was already shown above.

index.html:

```
<head>
<meta ..... />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
{{> index}}
</div>
</body>
```

cpd.html:

```
<template name="cpd">
....
<a name="events"></a>
....
</template>
```

Just extra information:

The Meteor version I am using contains jquery library and I have tested that my jquery works.

If I was not using meteor and using for example just HTML. This is easily done by adding '#' and the id at the end of your URL. Like www.example.com/cpdEvents#events

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you right but you can add hashtags in meteor too. Just route with iron-route r to a new hashtag by clicking your href.

```
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'posts.index'}}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'overview' hash='about'}}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'overview' hash='meetup'}}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker'></span>My Meetup</a></li>
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'overview' hash='contact'}}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span> Contact Me</a></li>
```

Than iron-router automatically scrolls to that hashtag if it is found on that page. By overriding the scrollToHash-function you can change the scroll behavior.

```
Router._scrollToHash = function(hash) {
  var section = $(hash);
  if (section.length) {
    var sectionTop = section.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: sectionTop
    }, "slow");
  }
};
```

Have a look on my website [Click](http://rico-ruszewski.com/#contact). There I have the access with the navbar on aboutme, meetup, contact by staying at the same page and just changing the hashtags.

Comment: I am +1'ing your answer because you just taught me something.  Thanks for that.

Comment: You understand me exactly right :) First thanks for your help. If I understand you correctly, meteor/iron router does support scroll to hash by default? So if my url is www.example.com/cpd#events, the browser window should by default scroll to the events anchor? If that is so, my scroll to hash is not working. On an unrelated subject, I like your website. Is there anything specific you did for your website to use low bandwidth, because mine uses 8MB the first time it loads?

Comment: Yep it jumps there by default. This site is my freetime project in order to improve my knowledge for details in meteor. If you want to reduce the size you need to deploy the project in production mode. Source code is available here https://github.com/Chaosbohne/bicobic

Comment: I figured out why yours work and mine does not. You are scrolling to anchors when you are already on the page. Where I click on a link on one of my different webpages that takes me to the page where I want the browser window to scroll to my anchor. For example on your web page, if I copy and paste 'http://rico-ruszewski.com/#meetup', into a blank new tab, the browser window is at the top of your web page. I then have to click on the 'My Meetup' link to scroll down to the anchor.\

Comment: Ah I've got it. Nice hint. Never tested this case. If I have some time I will investigate to look for a solution for automated hashtag scolling on new pages. What seems curios is in 2 out of 10 cases by using firefox the iron-router jumps to that hashtag even on a new blank page. But in 8 cases it doesn't. Don't know why.

Comment: @chaosbohne the link you've provided to your website no longer works. Link to GitHub should be sufficient though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll using jQuery like so:

```
$(document).scrollTop( $("#myElement").offset().top );
```

Where `#myElement` was the `id` of the element you want to jump to, like a div or such.

I would put this in my Template's rendered function like this:

Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
  $(document).scrollTop( $("#myElement").offset().top );
}

You could even get creative and pass in the element's ID you want to jump to as part of the data in your route, or through a Session variable.  Or through some other means.  Quite a few options, really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but not exactly what i am looking for. Because if you use the normal url www.example.com/cpd, the browser window must be at the top of the page. Where if you use the www.example.com/cpd#events url, the browser window must scroll to the events anchor. So if I use your code, the browser window will always open at the events anchor. But still your code did help me for a temporary solution. I can create multiple templates of the web page and just give them other names. So I then have multiple rendered functions I can use. But that is a lot of redundant code.